# Laravel Lighthouse GraphQL: Passport Authentication is not working even if the token is present the request header

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-passport, lighthouse, laravel-lighthouse

I am working on a Laravel project. I am building GraphQL API using Lighthouse library. I am using this library for Passport auth, https://github.com/joselfonseca/lighthouse-graphql-passport-auth. I could consume the endpoints from that library and generate the auth access tokens. I installed and configured the Passport beforehand. The problem is that when I consume an endpoint/ query a mutation that is protected, it is not working. Even if the token is present in the header, it is always returning false for checking if the user is logged in.

I have the following schema declaration.

```
extend type Mutation @middleware(checks: ["api", "auth.restaurant-admin"]) {
    updateUserProfile(input: UpdateUserProfileInput): User! @updateUserProfileValidation
}
```

As you can see, it is literally a mutation protected by "api" and "auth.restaurant-admin" middleware.

The following is my auth.restaurant-admin middleware implementation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Models\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class AuthRestaurantAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check() and auth()->user()->hasRole(User::ROLE_RESTAURANT_ADMIN)) {

            if (auth()->user()->restaurant) {
                return $next($request);
            } else {
                return abort(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, 'There is no restaurant assigned to the user');
            }
        }

        return abort(Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, 'You are not authorised to access this part of the application');
    }
}
```

The `auth()->check()` method always returns false even if the valid access token is present in the header. I pass the token as follow in the GraphQL playground.

```
[![enter code here][1]][1]
```

When I retrieve the token from the header like this, $request->header('Authorization'), I can see the expected value. But the auth()->check() just not working. What is wrong and missing in my code? How can I fix it?